# No notification when entering wrong password in module login

Tags: joomla-2.5, login

On http://www.belgianpainsociety.org you can login using the module login in the right sidebar. However, when people enter a wrong password and push enter, they get redirected to the previous, but no message is shown. There's no notification that says the password is wrong, so people might think they succeeded loging in.

Anyone knows how I can get a notification that my password is wrong?

I use Jomsocial. Joomla version is 2.5.28.

Comment: Your login module appear to be using Ajax which is not a default feature with Joomla. I'd suggest contacting the developer of your template and/or the JomSocial developers

Answer (score 2):

I would love to debug this but your website banned me with

> Your IP address has been blocked because there were too many
>   unsuccessful login attempts in a short time. Your IP address is:
>   xx.149.40.xx.

The problem is probably your custom template. To prove this switch back to the Joomla default template and try again - see if the message appears - if so then that proves its a custom template issue and you should then look for

```
<jdoc:include type="message" />
```

in your templates source file, it should be near

```
<jdoc:include type="component" />
```

also check any redirections you have set up in the login module.

Lastly - looking at the process when it submits the login form, it appears to be going to /en/ first, and then redirecting back to the home page without /en/, I see from the cookies that you have some language switcher installed - you might also want to try disabling that

[image: browser debug]